# Export DataStage Job Designs to .dsx file

Tags: datastage

I am trying to export the DataStage job designs with executables. Below is the screenshots I use to export from the GUI.

[image]

[image]

This is the two commands I use:

```
dsexport.exe /h=XX /U=XX /p=XX projectXXX /job=XXX jobname.dsx
dsexport.exe /h=XX /U=XX /p=XX projectXXX /job=XXX /EXEC /APPEND jobname.dsx
```

The file generated from commands is bigger than the one from GUI. Anyone knows how to use dsexport command to export jobs with the options as in the GUI screenshots. much appreciated. I am using Designer V8.5.

JS

Answer (score 0):

C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic>dsexport /d={ip address of server} /u={user id} /p={password} /job={job to export} {Project where job is located in} {FileName.dsx}

try this, it will export a single dsx file with all informations

P.S.I am using version 11.3

Answer (score 0):

As you can see GUI is excluding some read-only files which is not excluded in command line this is why the file size difference is there.

Answer (score 0):

You have "Include Dependent Items" unchecked in the GUI. The command line will include dependent items by default (i.e. shared containers or routines). You can disable this behaviour on the command line by using the /NODEPENDENTS command switch.